# Comparing 2 DF where one is a subset of the other and the values for the subset change and need to update the main one only for the inputs from subset

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison

I have one main data frame with 4 columns lets say:

- Wage
- Name
- Age
- Output (with a default value of 0).

This would be `df_main`. Then I am creating another dataframe based on this one but I filter it out based on persons with an age lower than 25. This would be `df_subset`. Then I want to compare each of the wages from the `df_subset` against a number. The output of the comparison I want to insert it in the `Output` in the `df_subset`, basically updating the default value it has already. Then I want to update the `Output` column in the `df_main` only for the persons from the `df_subset`. I am not working directly with the `df_main` because I do not want to apply the filters from above and lose the other entries.

Is it possible to do this in an optimum way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  mask to form the subset, change the subset ans use the same mask to write the changes back. See below for a very simple example of the approach. Note - you have to work on a copy of the masked subset.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                    'col2': [1.1, 1.3, 3.4, 4.5, 3.2, 2.6]
                    })


dfx = df[df['col1'] == 2].copy()
dfx['col2'].where(dfx['col2'] < 2.0, 9.9, inplace = True) # change some values
df['col2'][df['col1'] == 2] = dfx['col2'] # write changes back to df
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
# Create a boolean mask
m = df_main['Age'] < 25
df_subset = df_main.loc[m].copy()

# Compare each Wage against a number
number = 3000  # A number for what? Compute difference?
df_subset['Output'] = df_subset['Wage'] - number

# Returns to df_main without overriding existing values
df_main.loc[m, 'Output'] = df_subset['Output']
```

Output:

```
>>> df_main
    Wage  Age  Output
0   4658   50       0
1   4758   23    1758
2   4940   29       0
3   4184   37       0
4   4648   48       0
..   ...  ...     ...
95  1634   63       0
96  3446   23     446
97  2173   53       0
98  1225   44       0
99  3498   25       0

[100 rows x 3 columns]

>>> df_subset
    Wage  Age  Output
1   4758   23    1758
16  2063   21    -937
19  2191   22    -809
30  4552   21    1552
34  1920   23   -1080
42  1389   20   -1611
45  4640   24    1640
64  3065   24      65
76  3966   20     966
81  1033   20   -1967
82  1033   24   -1967
86  4655   22    1655
96  3446   23     446
```

A more straightforward way is:

```
df_main['Output'] = np.where(df_main['Age'] < 25,
                             df_main['Wage'] - number,  # Age < 25
                             df_main['Output'])  # Other
```

Input DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(2023)
df_main = pd.DataFrame({'Wage': np.random.randint(1000, 5000, 100),
                        'Age': np.random.randint(20, 65, 100),
                        'Output': 0})
print(df_main)

# Output, Name column is not significant here
    Wage  Age  Output
0   2893   34       0
1   1352   21       0
2   1629   23       0
3   1881   49       0
4   2193   34       0
..   ...  ...     ...
95  4404   31       0
96  2694   50       0
97  4371   33       0
98  3263   34       0
99  2719   45       0

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```